# running setInterval in all pages react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, setinterval

i want to timer module in my web app when user click start it will running and not stop until user stop it. here is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
 let secondsInterval = () => {};
  if (clockRunning) {
    secondsInterval = setInterval(() => {
      localStorage.setItem("seconds", seconds+1);
      setseconds((prev) => prev + 1);
      if (seconds == 59) {
        localStorage.setItem("minutes", minutes+1);
        setminutes((prev) => prev + 1);
        setseconds(0);
        if (minutes == 59) {
          localStorage.setItem("hours", hours+1);
          setminutes(0);
          sethours((prev) => prev + 1);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  return () => clearInterval(secondsInterval);
}, [seconds, clockRunning]);
```

if I remove clearInterval it will so much disturb in interval as it running anonymous.
how can i run this setinterval even the component will unmount i:e change the route .
i am using react-router-dom . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't run it whilst the component is unmounted, as that violates basic React principles. The hooks and everything related to them are "owned" by that component and when that's unmounted, everything gets cleaned up by design. Not clearing the interval would be a bug as you'd be calling setters that don't exist.

The answer is to hoist the state/hooks to a higher component like your application root, and then pass down the data via context or otherwise.

In a new file, `TimerContext`:

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const TimerContext = createContext({
    seconds: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    hours: 0,
    pauseClock: () => throw new Error('Must be called in context')
})
```

In a new file `TimerProvider`:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { TimerContext } from './TimerContext'

export const TimerProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(localStorage.getItem('seconds') ?? 0)
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(localStorage.getItem('minutes') ?? 0)
    const [hours, setHours] = useState(localStorage.getItem('hours') ?? 0)
    const [clockRunning, setClockRunning] = useState(0)

    const pauseClock = useCallback((run) => setClockRunning(run), [])

    useEffect(() => {
     let secondsInterval;
      if (clockRunning) {
          secondsInterval = setInterval(() => {
          localStorage.setItem("seconds", seconds+1);
          setseconds((prev) => prev + 1);
          if (seconds == 59) {
            localStorage.setItem("minutes", minutes+1);
            setminutes((prev) => prev + 1);
            setseconds(0);
            if (minutes == 59) {
              localStorage.setItem("hours", hours+1);
              setminutes(0);
              sethours((prev) => prev + 1);
            }
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
      return () => secondsInterval && clearInterval(secondsInterval);
    }, [clockRunning]);

    return <TimerContext.Provider value={{ seconds, minutes, hours, 
 pauseClock}}> 
        {children}
       </TimerContext.Provider>

}
```

In one of your high level components like App or something:

```
import { TimerProvider } from './TimerProvider'

// existing stuff

const App = () => {
   // Existing stuff

   return <TimerProvider>
         {/* Your existing app contents here */}
       </TimerProvider>

}
```

Wherever you need to get the data:

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { TimerContext } from './TimerContext'

const Consumer = () => {
   const { seconds, minutes, hours, pauseClock } = useContext(TimerContext)

}
```

Comment: i have used the context API but in this app I am using redux tool-kit. thanks for guiding i will be implement this. when the app refresh state will be it at his default value i have to set the default value from local storage. am I right?

Comment: Just added an edit to fix that

Comment: Btw I think it makes sense to do this over context and not Redux -- redux would be too heavy for this.

Comment: redux is already initialized i don't want to use two state management. thanks for guiding

Comment: @zeeshan Fair. One thing you might consider is instead of storing all the minutes/seconds/hours in the redux state (which will be quite noisy), you could instead keep that state down where it was originally and then on unmount, you could store the minutes/seconds/hours in redux AND the current date. Then when it remounts, initialise from that time and add on the difference between the new current time, and the stored one. Though it depends on if other components need it as this would only make sense if you only want to display the countdown, and not use it under the hood in other places.